# Solving multiple renders of component incl. useEffect, useState and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-state

I have a React functional component that is making an axios call, setting it to state, and will use that data in the render.

Current code:

WeatherPanel.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import getLocationData from "../api/getLocationData";

const WeatherPanel = () => {
  const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function populateLocationData() {
      const data = await getLocationData();
      setLocationData(data);
    }
    populateLocationData();
  }, []);

  return locationData ? (
    <>
      <div>Hello {locationData.woeid}</div>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>Loading</>
  );
};

export default WeatherPanel;
```

getLocationData.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const getLocationData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("/api/location/44418/");
  return response.data;
};

export default getLocationData;
```

Question:

It seems like I have to have the `locationData ? (` guard on the render, and therefore the Loading portion, as without it it tries to render before the useState within the useEffect has completed, resulting in `locationData.woeid` being undefined and breaking.

Is this the correct/best way to handle this? Is there a way for a functional component to have something complete before attempting the first render?

(I know the `<>Loading</>` should be replaced by a loading screen or spinner or something, more asking about the code structure).

Thanks!

Comment: You could keep a separate loading state instead...

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a loading state and deal with it like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import getLocationData from '../api/getLocationData';

const WeatherPanel = () => {
  const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function populateLocationData() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const data = await getLocationData();
        setLocationData(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
    populateLocationData();
  }, []);

  function renderWeahter() {
    if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    return <div>Hello {locationData.woeid}</div>;
  }

  return <div>{renderWeahter()}</div>;
};

export default WeatherPanel;
```